# Angular 2: file not found on local .json file

Tags: javascript, html, file, angular, ionic2

I have seen a few different posts about not being able to find local files to open them up whether they be images or data files, but none of the solutions have worked for me. My guess would be there is some configuration I'm missing.

The file I'm looking for is in a folder named "data" on the same level as my app.html and app.ts files.

Here is what I have in app.html, PS I'm also using Ionic2:

```
<ion-menu (click)='getDepartments()' side='right' type='overlay' [content]="content">
```

and in the app.ts file I have:

```
getDepartments() {
    this.http.get('/data/data.json')
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(
            data => this.departments = data,
            err => console.log(err),
            () => console.log('Random Quote Complete')
        );
}
```

I've tried:

```
./data/data.json

data/data.json

app/data/data.json
```

and any other path. And they all return a 404 file not found error. This seems just like growing pains with getting familiar with Angular 2. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Previous answers have said to put it directly in the `www` folder to make it available to the app.  I would say this is not the best solution as the `www` folder is excluded using `.gitignore` in a newly created Ionic2 project.

Instead put it inside the `src/assets` folder and it will also be made available in App and it will NOT be excluded from the git repo (by default).
Then you can access using: `this.http.get('assets/file.json');`

You could modify the .gitignore file, but then you may be including other unnecessary files.

Comment: after getting familiar with angular 2/4 months later i see that this answer is the correct long term solution. sorry it took so long to switch the check

Answer (score 2):

I didn't realize that working with Ionic that it compiles everything in the app folder and puts it into the www/build folder. Therefore when I put a path in the uncompiled app folder I didn't realize that the file I'm putting the path in isn't where I think it is.

So I did two things, each worked. I put the files directly in the www file (don't put them in the build file as they will be deleted every time you run ionic serve), and then fix the path accordingly. Or just fix the path knowing that when you look for a file in your app.ts, it needs to exit out of www/build first.

Answer (score 2):

For any anyone who is interested in resolving the same problem. If you are using Angular CLI and you want to make any folder accessible through http as in this case "data" folder.

Go to Angular-CLI.JSON  then add "the folder name" which is "data" under apps -> assets

```js
"apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico",
        "data"
      ],
```

Answer (score -2):

Is your server able to see the folder '/data'? Make sure your JSON file is located in the same directory as your public/static files.

Comment: It's all local so I would assume my 'server'/computer can see the /data folder. I don't have a public/static files directory in my project.