# Font url not working in angular 5 css reference

Tags: css, angular, image, angular-cli

I have created an angular 5 project with angular cli. referenced css in angular-cli.json style tag.

```
"styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "static/css/custom.css",
        "static/css/style.bundle.css",
        "static/css/vendors.bundle.css",
        "static/css/fullcalendar.bundle.css"
      ]
```

when i try to run app in browser. i get font files aborted error in console

```
GET http://localhost:4200/fonts/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0 net::ERR_ABORTED
fonts/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0:1 GET http://localhost:4200/fonts/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0 net::ERR_ABORTED
fonts/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0:1 GET http://localhost:4200/fonts/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0 net::ERR_ABORTED
```

these font files are being used in vendors.bundle.css

#### what have i tried:

- I tried to change url `src: url("fonts/socicon/socicon.eot")` to src: `url("/fonts/socicon/socicon.eot")` in css file.
- I tried to load css like this,

  `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" ref="./static/css/style.bundle.css"/>`

but it gave me this error

```
**because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled**
```

Comment: You might want to check out this link. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5213

Answer (score 0):

[Angular 2: file not found on local .json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37214014/angular-2-file-not-found-on-local-json-file/47681680#47681680)

It seems that the "static" folder not accessible. This previous issue may help.